# PreparedQuery from GAE Datastore to JSP

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Google App Engine with Java.

I use a Datastore Query to get back Entities from the datastore with the following code:

```
public static PreparedQuery GetAllEntities() {
        DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        Query q = new Query("Apple");
        PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(q);
        return pq;
    }
```

After that I would like to "give" this `pq` to the .jsp which should list the "name" property of all the entities. How is it possible to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have access to a `HttpServletRequest`? If so, add the result of `pq` to the request attributes.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. How should I handle it in the JSP?

Comment: Look into our wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info and use [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html)